# How to do CloudFront origin failover with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudfront

I've successfully setup CloudFront Origin Failover in the Management Console. I wonder how I can do the same using Terraform?

It's a very simple setup, two origins, one origin group with one primary and one secondary origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform does offer an [example configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudfront_distribution.html) of this in the documentation.

If you start with a simple CloudFront resource like the one below

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "s3_distribution" {    
  origin {
    domain_name = "${aws_s3_bucket.primary.bucket_regional_domain_name}"
    origin_id   = "primaryS3"

    s3_origin_config {
      origin_access_identity = "${aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.default.cloudfront_access_identity_path}"
    }
  }

  default_cache_behavior {
    # Note: Origin set to the single origin.
    target_origin_id = "primaryS3" 
  }
}
```

Then adding an Origin Failover configuration is rather easy.

1. Add the secondary origin.
2. Group it with the primary (order of members are important).
3. Set the default origin to be the group.

Here's an example (from the documentation):

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "s3_distribution" {
  origin_group {
    origin_id = "groupS3"

    failover_criteria {
      status_codes = [403, 404, 500, 502]
    }

    member {
      origin_id = "primaryS3"
    }

    member {
      origin_id = "failoverS3"
    }
  }

  # Primary Origin
  origin {
    domain_name = "${aws_s3_bucket.primary.bucket_regional_domain_name}"
    origin_id   = "primaryS3"

    s3_origin_config {
      origin_access_identity = "${aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.default.cloudfront_access_identity_path}"
    }
  }

  # Secondary Origin
  origin {
    domain_name = "${aws_s3_bucket.failover.bucket_regional_domain_name}"
    origin_id   = "failoverS3"

    s3_origin_config {
      origin_access_identity = "${aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.default.cloudfront_access_identity_path}"
    }
  }

  default_cache_behavior {
    # Important, use the failover group instead of the primary origin.
    target_origin_id = "groupS3" 
  }
}
```